# Dismiss Dialog if App is in Airplane mode?

Tags: android

I have an app in which user input his details in edit text and send Register request to server and after server success response a dialog will open and need confirmation by user here I want to check whether device is in airplane mode or not if yes then move Dismiss dialog otherwise send user details to server.

code:-

```
private final BroadcastReceiver m_oAIRPLANE_MODE_CHECKER = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        otpRequest();
    }
};
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Log.i(TAG, "onCreate..............");
    setContentView(R.layout.registration_screen);
    defaultConfigration();// defining default configuration
    init();// Initialize controls

    /*Registered Broadcast receiver*/
    IntentFilter m_intentFilter = new IntentFilter();// creating object of Intentfilter class user for defining permission
    m_intentFilter.addAction("android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE");// action to check Internet connection
    getApplicationContext().registerReceiver(m_oInternetChecker, m_intentFilter);// register receiver....

    m_oAirplaneModeIntent = new IntentFilter();
    m_intentFilter.addAction("android.intent.action.AIRPLANE_MODE");
    getApplicationContext().registerReceiver(m_oAIRPLANE_MODE_CHECKER,m_oAirplaneModeIntent);
}
/*Unregistered broadcast receiver*/
@Override
public void onDestroy() {// unregister broadcast receiver ........
    super.onDestroy();
    Log.i(TAG, "onDestroy.............");
    getApplicationContext().unregisterReceiver(m_oInternetChecker);// unregistaer broadcast receiver.
    getApplicationContext().unregisterReceiver(m_oAIRPLANE_MODE_CHECKER);
}
```

here I want to make a check

```
String sourceString = "We will send you a verification SMS to this Number.<br/><br/> <b><font color='#2196F3'>" + s_szResponseMobileNum + "</b> <br/><br/>Please ensure that this number is active on this device.";
                        m_OTPAlertBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(CRegistrationScreen.this, R.style.AppCompatAlertDialogStyle);
                        m_OTPAlertBuilder.setCancelable(false);
                        m_OTPAlertBuilder.setMessage(Html.fromHtml(sourceString));
                        m_OTPAlertBuilder.setPositiveButton(R.string.ok, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                /*This method send request to server to generate OTP*/
                                /* condition to check whether app is in background*/
                                if (NetworkUtil.isAppIsInBackground(getApplicationContext())) {
                                            /*if app is in background then start service*/
                                    Intent i = new Intent(CRegistrationScreen.this, OtpGenrateService.class);
                                    getApplicationContext().startService(i);
                                } else {
                                            /*if app is in forground the send data to server*/
                                            /*this method genrate otp */
                                    generateOtp();
                                }

                            }
                        });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check if device is in airplane mode using this snippet:

```
public static boolean isInAirplaneModeOn(Context context){
    return Settings.System.getInt(context.getContentResolver(), Settings.System.AIRPLANE_MODE_ON, 0) != 0;
}
```

Also, you can set up broadcast receiver to receive [ACTION_AIRPLANE_MODE_CHANGED](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_AIRPLANE_MODE_CHANGED) broadcast. Programatically:

```
BroadcastReceiver receiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
      @Override
      public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
          // do your stuff here
          boolean inAirplaneMode = AirplaneModeHelper.isInAirplaneMode(context);
          Log.i("AIRPLANE", "In airplane mode: " + inAirplaneMode);
      }
};
context.registerReceiver(receiver, new IntentFilter("android.intent.action.ACTION_AIRPLANE_MODE_CHANGED"));
```

Or using manifest:

```
<receiver android:enabled="true" android:name=".YourReceiver">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.ACTION_AIRPLANE_MODE_CHANGED"/>
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```